# Emacs font lock mode: provide a custom color instead of a face

Tags: emacs, colors, elisp, customization, emacs-faces

On [this page discussing font lock mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html), an example is provided which highlights a custom pattern:

```
 (add-hook 'c-mode-hook
           (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil
             '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 font-lock-warning-face t)))))
```

Is there a way to provide a custom color instead of `font-lock-warning-face` and **without** defining a new custom face. I want to be able to write something like:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 "Blue" t)))
```

or an RGB color definition:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 "#F0F0F0" t)))
```

Using the double quotes doesn't work. Do you know what **will** make it work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 '(:foreground "blue") t)))
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 '(:foreground "#F0F0F0") t)))
```

A full list of attributes is in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html).

Comment: Thank you for the clear concise answer, I should have known that.

Comment: nschum, how to add more properties to the face like making it bold?
I tried something like:
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 '(:foreground "blue" :bold t) t)))
But that did not work.

Comment: Your approach is correct, but :bold is not a valid text property. Try :weight and check the link for more details.