# How to highlight percentage sign "%" for fortran code in emacs?

Tags: emacs, fortran, syntax-highlighting

How can I highlight in Emacs the percentage sign "%" for accessing members of a type?

Comment: Show your code first.

Comment: @Amit Which code? There is only one place this character can be in a Fortran code outside of character strings so there is no real need for a Fortran code. Or do you want the Emacs configuration code?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'f90-mode
        '(("%" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

This highlights `%` in the same colour as keywords like `if`, `then`, `call`, etc. There are a load of predefined faces listed in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces-for-Font-Lock.html), or you can specify a face [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6259402/2043465).

Comment: Thanks, that works. And if I want to give it a different color than all the other defined faces?

Comment: I've added a link to a way to set the face manually, but it doesn't seem to work for me so YMMV.

Comment: @HansMaulwurf If this answered your question, feel free to accept it (under the vote arrows)