# Syntax highlighting for non-alphanumeric characters in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I would like for certain non-alphanumeric characters (= + / < > etc.) to be highlighted in emacs while editing any language.

Using the answer to [a different question on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631578/how-to-highlight-percentage-sign-for-fortran-code-in-emacs), I found this solution for highlighting '%' while editing Fortran:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'f90-mode
        '(("%" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

but this is only one symbol in one language. I can achieve what I want by polluting my .emacs file:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
        '(("=" . font-lock-keyword-face)))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'java-mode
        '(("=" . font-lock-keyword-face)))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'python-mode
        '(("=" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

and so on, but this introduces a bug in which the last few lines of any file do not get any syntax highlighting at all.

How can I, across all language modes, enable syntax highlighting for a certain set of non-alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 3):

Use library [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowWhiteSpace#HighlightChars) (the code is [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el)).

You can highlight any set of characters, using any faces. You can define the set using any number of entries of any of these kinds:

- string of chars
- range of successive chars (Emacs characters are integers)
- character class (e.g. `[:nonascii:]`, `[:space:]`)
- character set (e.g. `iso-8859-1` or `lao`)

You can also *exclude* any set of characters from such highlighting.

You can thus, for example, highlight all characters in character set `greek-iso8859-7` except the character `GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA`. Or highlight all characters in class `[:space:]` (whitespace) except `tab`. Or all Unicode characters in the range `?\u2190` through `?\u21ff` (mathematical arrows) except `?\u21b6`, `?\u21b7`, `?\u21ba`, and `?\u21bb` (curved arrows)...

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close to what I wanted. After using `M-x hc-highlight-chars` and entering the characters I want highlighted, the highlights are only shown in the current buffer and are removed completely after exiting emacs. Is there any way to make the highlights persistent and shown across all buffers?

Comment: See the part of the file Commentary that starts "*But if you want to use a particular kind of highlighting by default globally, then just add the corresponding `hc-highlight-*` function to the hook `font-lock-mode-hook`.*".

Comment: IOW, yes, you can make it global, and rehighlight automatically. In a way, that is "permanent" highlighting. (The only other kind of permanent highlighting in Emacs is via *Enriched* mode. See [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary#PermanentHighlighting) for more about that.)

Comment: I added `(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-chars)` to my .emacs file and now all of my syntax highlighting is gone. When I remove that line and restart emacs, the syntax highlighting is still not working.

Comment: If you removed the line you added, and you saw in the next Emacs session that things do not work, then it sounds like you changed something else, besides just adding (and then removing) that line.