# How to customize colors in f90-mode emacs?

Tags: emacs, fortran, customization

When I use emacs in f90mode, some instructions appear in a different color (like size, if, print, end, do, etc.). I would like to set up that very same color for a number of functions I defined. How could I accomplish this? Is there any file I could customize?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, my `.emacs` file contain these lines, which seems to change colors for Fortran sources (I guess I consulted some page like [this one](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces-for-Font-Lock.html), but do not remember details, sorry...)

```
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "green")
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-keyword-face "lightblue")
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-type-face "green")
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-function-name-face "pink")
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-variable-name-face "black")
;; the above colors are just random examples...
```

Also, we can [change the color of `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631578/how-to-highlight-percentage-sign-for-fortran-code-in-emacs)(the selector symbol of type components) by

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'f90-mode
        '(("%" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

where `font-lock-keyword-fact` is the color specified above. By using the above commands, it may be possible to customize the color as you like (to some extent).