# Overriding emacs org-mode faces

Tags: emacs, colors, org-mode, font-lock

I am trying to override the default syntax highlighting in `org-mode` and `org-agenda-mode` buffers.

To clarify my intention: my current reason for doing this is to highlight headings (or parts of headings) based on their tags. The built-in variable `org-tag-faces` only allows customisation of the tag itself, not the heading containing the tag.

With reference to the following related questions:

1. [Emacs font lock mode: provide a custom color instead of a face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258455/emacs-font-lock-mode-provide-a-custom-color-instead-of-a-face)
2. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/color-code-a-new-generic-character-combination
3. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8222/how-to-make-the-custom-font-lock-keywords-not-override-the-default-major-mode-fo#comment12615_8222

In thread 2 the accepted answer is to use font-lock for this purpose.

In thread 3 I am trying to achieve the exact opposite of the poster. The last comment by [Jordon Biondo](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/160/jordon-biondo) says:

> take out the t from your keywords, what that t specifies is that font-lock should override already colored things.

Since I want to override already coloured things I am adding in the t but as far as I can tell the `org-mode` highlighting is still overriding my custom face.
In `org-mode` buffers this manifests as the main body of the heading text being changed but any other items such as todo-states, dates, tags etc. retaining there existing faces.
In `org-agenda-mode` buffers it completely fails to modify any aspect of the matched lines.

By way of a simple example here is some code I'm trying to use to set any lines containing :TT: to red in `org-mode` buffers:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
                (lambda ()
                  (font-lock-add-keywords
                   'org-mode
                   '(
                     ("^.*:TT:.*$" 0 '(:foreground "#FF0000") t)
                   ))))
```

Comment: just curious, why would you want to change the default syntax highlighting of `org-mode` and `org-agenda-mode` ?

Comment: I want to be able to change the colour of items based on their tags. Using font-lock is the accepted answer in http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/color-code-a-new-generic-character-combination.

Comment: `org-agenda-mode` does *not* use `font-lock`, so any efforts to incorporate that feature will not work well.  Instead, the `org-agenda-mode` involves placement of text-properties with faces as the items are being gathered from the main buffer.

Comment: Unfortunately, a modification of the `text-property` placement in `org-agenda-mode` buffers is too complex to place in an answer because there are multiple functions that can be used to gather data and place faces as the `*Org Agenda*` mode buffer is being created.  If you are really motivated and want the easiest approach using `text-properties`, you can modify `org-format-item` which is a last ditch effort to change things before the buffer is populated.  The best approach, is to locate and modify the functions that gather that data.

Comment: @lawlist I think your comments should be the accepted answer - can you re-post as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The question has different answers for `org-mode` and for `org-agenda-mode`.  I haven't played around a whole lot with changing `org-mode` default highlighting, but it's complex -- without investing time, I don't know whether it's better to modify `org-set-font-lock-defaults`, or some of the functions used therein, or the ramifications of simply trying to use `font-lock-add-keywords`.  And, as mentioned, `org-agenda-mode` is complicated too.  It is a "Pandora's Box" that I'm not prepared to open by posting an answer -- sorry . . . .  I'll leave that to someone much braver than myself.  :)

Comment: @lawlist: _"I'll leave that to someone much braver than myself"_ - you and me both!

Answer (score 0):

This mostly works for me:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (font-lock-add-keywords
         'org-mode
         '(("^.*:TT:.*$" . font-lock-warning-face)))))
```

The headline is red, although the tag itself is not.

Comment: Since `org-agenda-mode` does not use `font-lock`, this solution is not ideal for `*Org Agenda*` buffers.  If you `(require 'org-agenda)` and then look at the code for `org-agenda-mode` by typing `M-x find-function RET org-agenda-mode RET` , you will see a notation as follows:   `;; Keep global-font-lock-mode from turning on font-lock-mode` and the code below is:  `(org-set-local 'font-lock-global-modes (list 'not major-mode))`

Comment: This code gives the same result as my code in the original post: _"In org-mode buffers this manifests as the main body of the heading text being changed but any other items such as todo-states, dates, tags etc. retaining there existing faces."_